# Alamofire 4.4.0: Extra Argument 'Method' in Call: Do not know What is Throwing Error

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I have an alamofire request in swift and am not sure why it is throwing `Extra Argument 'Method' in Call`:

```
Alamofire.request(
                URL(string: "https://api.io"),
                method: .post,
                parameters: [
                    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                    "client_id": "user00941",
                    "client_secret": "ILGddu8y8g7qW"
                ],
                encoding: .urlEncodedInURL
                ).response {

                    request, response, data, error in

                    let json = JSON(data: data!)

                    print("OAuth 2 token obtained from API: \(json["access_token"])")

                    let token = "Bearer \(json["access_token"].stringValue)"

            }
```

I have been looking at various other posts but cannot seem to find one with a solution that fits my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [your original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44318618/1) was that you were using the [argument label](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) `url` even though the [`Alamofire.request` function signature](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/c8700ac7ea6b7efa7200e2920bf528e88b4dbee6/Source/Alamofire.swift#L132-L138) has omitted it:

```
public func request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
```

Removing `url:` from your function call will take care of *that* error, but Swift should then remind you that a "value of optional type 'URL?' [is] not unwrapped." Although you *could* use [forced unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID332) to extract the value of the URL, I would recommend using [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) instead:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://api.io") {
    Alamofire.request(
                    URL(string: "https://api.io"),
                    method: .post,
                    parameters: [
                        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                        "client_id": "user00941",
                        "client_secret": "ILGddu8y8g7qW"
                    ],
                    encoding: .urlEncodedInURL
                    ).response {
                        request, response, data, error in

                        let json = JSON(data: data!)

                        print("OAuth 2 token obtained from API: \(json["access_token"])")

                        let token = "Bearer \(json["access_token"].stringValue)"
                   }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `guard` statement to preserve a [Golden Path](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#golden-path) through your code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.io") else {
    return
}
```

Comment: No... Same: Extra Argument Method in Call

Comment: I figured out the issue, you can see my answer.

Comment: Don't bother with `URL` at all. The `request` accepts `String` representation of URL, so just use that.

Answer (score 0):

This code has several errors. The encoding parameter needs to be set to `JSONEncoding.default` not `.urlEncodedInURL`.

In addition to this, the `request, response, data, error in` needs to be changed to `response in`. To get the data and error use `response.data` and `response.error`.